# Installation freeze due to RAID0?

Tags: system-installation, hardware

I'm trying to install the version 0.4.1 Loki, but it freeze (holds forever) on the first screen (blank 'e' logo on black background).

I had to do some extra step to install Windows10 on this computer because I've configured a RAID0 and needed to provide specific driver provided by my mobo manufacturer (Gigabyte, B350 Gamming 3).

it's the first time I'm trying to install an other OS than windows, but I would guess the issue might be also related to the raid0.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like graphics driver issue to me.Could you try the graphics fix?

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4700/11922